# Hausdorff dimension of the Cantor Staircase if redefined to be zero outside of the Cantor set

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

Let $f$ be the Cantor Staircase function redefined to be zero outside the Cantor set.

The Hausdorff dimension of its graph is greater than one. How can it be computed precisely?